# Dependent variable names in Idris

Tags: idris, dependent-type

Can I specify the name of a dependent variable in Idris?
I'd like to dynamically generate a function which accepts natural numbers which are *named* just like the input vector of chars?
Is this possible in Idris?

I have a working function `fn` which creates a dependent function, but with incorrectly named variables.

```
fn : Vect n Char -> Type -> Vect m Nat -> Type
fn [] a ys = Tensor ys a
fn (x :: xs) a ys = (i : Nat) -> fn xs a (i::ys)


data Tensor : Vect rank Nat -> Type -> Type where
    ....
```

Expected result:

```
λΠ> fn ['i','j','k'] Double []
(i : Nat) -> (j : Nat) -> (k : Nat) -> Tensor [i, j, k] Double : Type
```

Actual result:

```
λΠ> fn ['i','j','k'] Double []
(i : Nat) -> (i1 : Nat) -> (i2 : Nat) -> Tensor [i2, i1, i] Double : Type
```

Comment: might work using metaprogramming and quoting, probably difficult though